# How can I create Ubuntu users in a small office so they all can login in any computer in the room?

Tags: server, authentication

We started a small company and we want to run Ubuntu on all computers. We want to create a new Ubuntu account for each new team member in a way that each person can use any computer in the office and keep their settings, desktop, and basic files. We don't want to have a local server since all we do is cloud-based. We are open to buying a hire a server to do authentications (if that's what we need?). We only use GSuite for now for file syncing.

How can manage (add/edit/delete) those users?

I don't know the technical name for this but I think it exists. I am not a technical person but not afraid to learn.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are willing to invest in a small office server, a crude way to do this would be to put every user's  `/home/username` directory on a shared system (NFS or Samba), and create symbolic links to these directories on every computer. All of their settings, desktop and basic files would actually reside on the server.  Making backups is quite simple that way. However, people should not be able to log in to two computers at the same time, or things will get out of sync.

Comment: thanks @Jos! would it be possible to use a remote server (AWS) instead of local server? that would make the thing so slow since its working against a remote server? 

the thing is that each team member here has 8 to 9 different accounts for different SaaS services they use every day. If they have to login to each of them it would be a waste of time. Ideally their browser should keep the settings and logins after they log in in one of the computers here.

Comment: Putting this on an AWS server would give you a horrible performance. Especially browsers generate a lot of traffic to and from the cache in your home directory. Even a local superfast network server would be a trade-off, let alone a cloud server.

Comment: You need a local server for authentication. There are many ways to do authentication, as well. You don't necessarily need a networked filesystem for home directories. That is something beyond just login. If you need to keep browser data in sync though, then you'll need something like it. Really it's overly complex, and people will end up always using the same PC anyway, because they're going to keep their coffee and other trinkets at the one desk they always use.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you need three things:

- LDAP server: which handles the authentication part. There you can access the database of users (create, update and delete them)
- NFS filesystem: which syncronizes the home folders of your users across the different PCs (as an alternative you can look at GlusterFS)
- A local server (with appropriate storage)

If you want just the authentication part, then LDAP alone should be enough (and you can host the LDAP on a VPS, no need for a local server). If you also need the syncing of the home directories then an NFS filesystem and a local server is required.